# How can I import a pg_dump via PgAdmin4 without psql? "[archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Use psql."

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import a pg_dump from a Linux machine called "dump.sql" into a windows machine that has PgAdmin4 that does not have psql working.

I keep getting this error message:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the file isn't too big, simply load it into the query tool, then run it. But I don't think that pgAdmin supports the  `COPY FROM stdin` that is used in a `pg_dump` plain text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.

One problem is the `COPY FROM STDIN` that you can find in an SQL dump, and the other is the `\c` command you will find in dumps created with `-C`.

Not sure if there are more problems, but these are definitely showstoppers.

Did you delete the `psql` executable?
I have not seen a Windows pgAdmin installation without a `psql.exe` so far.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. So installed pgAdmin again and psql.exe was there, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: For others who happen across this: If you do `pg_dump` with flag `--insert` it will output in a format that can be run as a standard SQL query.